# GMGridViewCell CustomView Button action method is not getting called?

Tags: objective-c, ios, gmgridview, gmgridviewcell

I have a view controller with GMGridView in which I have 4 GMGridViewCells. For each cell view I am using individual view controller view's as the content view of the cell.My view controllers which are being loaded into the GMGridVeiwCell's are having buttons. When I tap on the buttons within the GMGridViewCell the IBAction methods of the buttons are not getting called. Can anyone help me on this? How can I catch the button actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to override `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` in `GMGridView` class like this one:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if(gestureRecognizer == _tapGesture) {

        UIView* touchedView = [touch view];
        if([touchedView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Said this, you could rely on this discussion for further info: [GMGridView discussion](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView/issues/68#issuecomment-5781322).

Let me know if this does fix the problem. Furthermore, why do you a controller for each custom view? I think the simplest manner to achieve your goal is to create a delegate for your custom view. The delegate will be the controller that contains the `GMGridView`. When you click the button in the custom view, you call the delegate and then respond according.

Hope that helps.